# wxRichTextCtrl not freeing memory with method Delete()

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, wxwidgets, richtext

I am writing a logging application that receives data and prints a log in a wxRichTextCtrl box with colored lines. First, I store the log lines in a vector of structures containing both the text and the color information, then a wxTimer() event triggers a function that reads the content of the vector and appends it to the rich text window.

When the rich text buffer reaches 250 lines, I delete the oldest line so to always have a maximum number of 250 lines displayed in the log window. Apparently, though, this doesn't free memory. Having a look at the memory usage by my executable in the task manager, I can see the used memory increasing at every new line, even though the program is correctly deleting the oldest lines. Is this a known bug of wxRichTextCtrl?

Here's some excerpt from my code:

Declarations:

```
wxRichTextCtrl *lstEventList;
// A vector of structures, a nice way to create a multi-dimensional vector
struct MidiLogStruct { wxString Text; wxColour Color; };
vector<MidiLogStruct> MidiLog;
```

In the logging function:

```
// eventLog is a wxString object containing the text
// eventColor is a wxColour object defining the text color
const MidiLogStruct thisLog = {eventLog, eventColor};
MidiLog.push_back(thisLog);
```

In the timer function filling the display box:

```
// Show all data stored in buffer
for (unsigned int i=0; i < MidiLog.size(); ++i)
{
    lstEventList->SetInsertionPointEnd();                           // Set cursor after the last character
    lstEventList->Newline();                                        // Add a new CRLF
    lstEventList->BeginTextColour(MidiLog[i].Color);                // Set text color
    lstEventList->WriteText(MidiLog[i].Text);                       // Write text
    lstEventList->ShowPosition(lstEventList->GetLastPosition());    // Make sure the last line is in view
}

// Clear buffer
MidiLog.clear();

// Delete all lines that exceed the max NUMOFMIDILOGLINES
if (lstEventList->GetNumberOfLines() > NUMOFMIDILOGLINES)
    lstEventList->Delete(wxRichTextRange(0, lstEventList->XYToPosition(0, lstEventList->GetNumberOfLines() - NUMOFMIDILOGLINES)));
```

Comment: Have you seen ***[This](http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=34641)***?

Comment: Yes, I already use BeginSuppressUndo() globally but that doesn't seem to help.